# Parameter Estimation via MCMC

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, estimation, sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo

In general, we use MCMC method to sample from a distribution which is hard to compute. In Bayesian setting, we sample from the posterior distribution of the random parameters defining the underlying distributions via MCMC.

My question is, by using MCMC, how can we **estimate** the parameters? What are the methods out there?

Answer (score 3):

The samples from the posterior allow you to compute expectations of the parameters.  From Betancourt's *A Conceptual Introduction to Hamiltonian Monte Carlo*...

> Given  sufficient  time,  the  history  of  the  Markov  chain,$\{q_0,...,q_N\}$,  denoted samples generated  by  the  Markov  chain,  becomes  a  convenient  quantification  of  the  typical  set.In particular, we can estimate expectations across the typical set, and hence expectations across the entire parameter space, by averaging the target function over this history
>
> $$\hat{f}_{N}=\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^{N} f\left(q_{n}\right)$$

So if you want to estimate parameters for, say, a model then you have to compute the expectation of the samples for that parameter.

Comment: You don't have to compute expectations to form an estimate.  For example, you might be interested in a maximum a posteriori (MAP) estimate, in which case you'd use an estimate of the maximum density region of the generated samples, or in an estimate which minimizes a custom loss function, as in inventory control.

Comment: @jbowman the reason I use MCMC sampling is that the posterior is a very complicateed distribution. Can I still estimate these parameters without computing the posterior via MAP?

Thanks for your anwser!

Comment: @jbowman  That is true, but there are good reasons to use expectations over MAP (as outlined in that paper).  In any case, you are right that "estimate" depends on what you want to know about the posterior, which is not necessarily the expectation.

Comment: @independentvariable - MAP estimation would use the output of the MCMC sampler as an input - but I meant it as an example of an estimator of the parameters other than the average of the output samples, not as a blanket recommendation.